# How do you check to see if Hyper-V is enabled using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that checks the Windows Optional Features to see if Hyper-V is installed. However, my code is not working. Even when Hyper-V is disabled, the script outputs that it is already enabled.

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Get the Hyper-V feature and store it in $hyperv
$hyperv = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online

# Check if Hyper-V is already enabled.
if($hyperv.State = "Enabled") {
    Write-Host "Hyper-V is already enabled."
} else {
    Write-Host "Hyper-V is disabled."
}
```

There is no error when the code is run.

Comment: It's always good to post also the error you're getting

Comment: There is no error when the code is run.

Comment: `=` is only for storing values in PowerShell.  To do an `is equal to` comparison, you have to use the `-eq` syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe it has to do with your `if` condition, try this:

```
if($hyperv.State -eq "Enabled")
```

The `=` sign is not going to work, you need to do it PowerShell way

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. It seems like the = was resetting the value of $hyperv.

Comment: @EvanAmara In most programming languages one equal sign (=) assigns a value and 2 equal signs (==) compare values. In powershell -eq (meaning equal) compares if 2 values are equal. If you need to know if the values are different you can use -ne (not equal). Check this website for more info on comparing values https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html

Comment: Is it possible to check if hyper-v is also running? Usually this requires a reboot and until then this command reports that the feature is enabled even if it's not actually running.

Answer (score 23):

Here's the full powershell script that works for me. Just copy and paste it into an elevated powershell then press enter.

```
$hyperv = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online
# Check if Hyper-V is enabled
if($hyperv.State -eq "Enabled") {
    Write-Host "Hyper-V is enabled."
} else {
    Write-Host "Hyper-V is disabled."
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### For Windows 10 Pro / Education / Enterprise

```
if ((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online).State -ne 'Enabled')
{
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
}
```

### For Windows Server

```
if ((Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V).Installed -eq $false)
{
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools
}
```

### Generic script

```
Write-Host "Enabling Hyper-V in host..."
if ((Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -match 'Microsoft Windows 10')
{
    if ((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online).State -ne 'Enabled')
    {
        Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
    }
}
if ((Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption -match 'Microsoft Windows Server')
{

    if ((Get-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V) -eq $false)
    {
        Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V -IncludeManagementTools
    }
}
```

Answer (score -7):

An easier way to do that is to go to Services by clicking the Start button and typing Services.msc and scrolling down to the Hyper-V Host Compute Service and seeing if it running. Also check the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service.

If they are both running you can safely assume that Hyper-V is running and active. My machine Windows 10 Pro with VMWARE Workstation 14.

Comment: Using PowerShell

Comment: the OP asked for help with doing this _programmatically_, preferably using powershell. your method is not at all suitable for the scenario listed - and that scenario is fairly sensible. [*grin*]