# What is the proper way to check if HyperV is running?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, hypervisor

I am trying to write a powershell script to install and set up Hyper-V machines. The install seems to be ok, however, I get contradictory responses from the system.
Basically, I use the `(gcim Win32_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent` to determine if HyperV is running.

It return **False**.

There is a similar class with the same member `(gcim CIM_ComputerSystem).HypervisorPresent` what is also returning **False**.

Also found this question [How do you check to see if Hyper-V is enabled using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567596/how-do-you-check-to-see-if-hyper-v-is-enabled-using-powershell)
 and this state property is **Enabled**

Do I miss something? These queries aren't the same? Could you point if any of these are deprecated?
Am I totally fooled, and Enabled means the system is capable to run HyperV, but actually it is not running?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CIM and WMI are a long tale but the short summary is that WMI is a Microsoft implementation of the OMI Standards defined by the DMTF, the Distributed Management Task Force, to come up with an industry wide standard.  So, of course, creating one new standard resulted in a bunch of different implementations, which are basically their own standard.

But otherwise CIM and WMI can be thought of as different gateways to the same information for Windows computers.  Different doors to the same house.  [More on that history and the distinctions here.](https://donjones.com/2015/04/14/omi-cim-wmi/)

When I run the PowerShell commands you shared (either of them) on my machine with Hyper-V present, even when running as a standard, non-admin user, I get `True` back for both.

You can also check to see if the BIOS firmware has virtualization enabled by looking in the `CIM_Processor` class.

```
(Get-CimInstance win32_processor).VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled
True
```

You could also check to see if the Windows Feature is installed but that doesn't give you the full picture (what if the Windows feature is enabled in an image applied to a machine without virtualization components enabled in the BIOS, for instance.)

```
[ADMIN] C:\>(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online).State
Enabled
```

Also, that technique  requires admin permissions.

Another way, and maybe the easiest is to check is to see if the `Hyper-V Computer Service` is running, which is needed for any VMs to launch, and can only run if everything else on the machine is done correctly to enable Hyper-V.

```
Get-Service vmcompute

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  vmcompute          Hyper-V Host Compute Service
```

We used to deploy servers with a MDT Task Sequence and enable Hyper-V along the way.  It required reboots and special commands to run to apply the right bios settings.  Then, we could enable the Windows Features, but those required two reboots, so it was quite tricky to handle with most imaging systems.  Our final 'Sanity Check' was whether the Hyper-V compute service was running.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It turned out that the BIOS is outdated. However, the virtualization is enabled in the BIOS settings, the win32_processor.virtualization returns false.

Comment: You do have to enable Hyper-V's required features in the BIOS first before enabling the Windows features will work.  It's called 'Single Root IO Virtualization', (SR-IOV) or sometimes `Intel VT-x` or `AMD-V`.  When those are enabled (in the BIOS), this should work.

Comment: On Windows 11 with Windows Sandbox enabled, `Get-Service vmcompute` shows `vmcompute` as running despite both `(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online).State` returning `Disabled` and `(Get-CimInstance win32_processor).VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled` returning `False`

Comment: This was very promising, until I realized that if you enable Hyper-V, notice the service is running, and then you disable Hyper-V, the service is still running...it does not seem to get stopped, making it an imperfect test for "is Hyper-V enabled".  More like "Was it ever enabled?"