# Win32_Processor VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled always returns False

Tags: vb.net, winapi, virtualization, vt-x

I try to query if Virtualization (VTx) is enabled on the System via VB.net

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "root\CIMV2",
            "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                MsgBox(queryObj("VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled"))
            Next
```

Altough it is enabled in the BIOS, and I can run 64-Bit Guest Systems in my VirtualBox, Win32_Processor is always reporting false.

[image]

If I have a look in the Task - Manager, it states "Virtualization: enabled"
[image]

Is there another possibility to query the VTx Status?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer to: [What is the proper way to check if HyperV is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191833/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-if-hyperv-is-running).The same problem is mentioned in the comments, check if you enable Hyper-V's required features in the BIOS.

Comment: Hello,
I've already read that Question before. But I am not running Hyper-V, I am running VirtualBox. And as you can see in the Screenshot, Task Manager states that Virtualization is enabled, but the Powershell Command does not, that's a strange behaviour I think.

Comment: I tested Win32_Processor on multiple devices and it returned the correct results for me. Maybe you need to check your BIOS settings and other environment configurations to determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: But the BIOS settings are correct, I can run VMs, and the Task Manager also displays a working virtualization environment !?

Comment: I am also running into the problem of inconsistency about this issue. Even though, I do get the correct values, the fact that I have seen so many people have this issue, I am afraid it is not a reliable way of checking virtualization capabilities. Have you found a solution in the meantime @Manuel?